# Use of self in Python

Tags: python, self

The other day I was trying on some easy exercises in Python3 and, since I'm pretty new in Python, I have some doubts about the `self`concept.

Below an exercise taken from HackerRank's 30-days-ofcode challenge.
Based on the input's values, I have to evaluate one person's age printing out differents outputs:

**Input (stdin)**

```
4
-1
10
16
18
```

**Code**

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,initialAge):
        # Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
        if initialAge < 0:
            self.age = 0
            print("Age is not valid, setting age to 0.")
        else:
            self.age = initialAge

    def amIOld(self):
        # Do some computations in here and print out the correct statement to the console
        if age < 13:
            print("You are young.")
        elif age >= 13 and age < 18:
            print("You are a teenager.")
        elif age >= 18:
            print("You are old.")

    def yearPasses(self):
        # Increment the age of the person in here    
        global age
        age += 1
```

**And then**

```
    t = int(input())
    for i in range(0, t):
        age = int(input())         
        p = Person(age)  
        p.amIOld()
        for j in range(0, 3):
            p.yearPasses()       
        p.amIOld()
        print("")
```

What I'm wondering is why in the `def amIOld(self)` part, the code below (with the use of `self.age` instead of `age`) is not working:

```
def amIOld(self):
    # Do some computations in here and print out the correct statement to the console
    if self.age < 13:
        print("You are young.")
    elif self.age >= 13 and self.age < 18:
        print("You are a teenager.")
    elif self.age >= 18:
        print("You are old.")
```

Can anyone be so kind to explain me the difference?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly  because you have ```selfage>=13``` rather than ```self.age>=13```

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the unintended typo. But even now it has no influence on the rest of code because it is not working as I was expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the line

```
elif selfage >= 13 and self.age < 18:
```

You are having a typo; That should be `self.age` over there, to access the `age` attribute of the class.

---

Using the self attributes is pretty crucial in OOP, because it is the guideline to accessing and regarding object's properties. The same way you should make the `yearPasses` method:

```
def yearPasses(self):
    self.age += 1 # increment the self attribute of age
```

instead of incrementing an arbitary, external, global variable named `age`.

In human terms - you don't increase just an `age`; you increase the age of **this** person, and later you will use **this** age for other purposes.

Comment: Obliviously the typo was an unintended error of the transcription. The code you are referring to with the `self.age` is not working as I was expecting before writing this post.

Comment: look at what i've added about `yearPasses`. the error is derived from it (when you use it in your code).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is now working well as expected. I did follow a guide on the discussion forum that was pointing out how the `global age` was a must to solve this problem :/ But I guess they were wrong

Answer (score 0):

self is used for representation of class object.For example if we look into your code.

Person is a class(class Person:) and we can mention any name as object for a class like:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,initialAge):
        #your code

person=Person(10) #or
per=Person(20) #or
per1=Person(5) #in your code class object has only one parameter rather than object(self).
```

if u want to call a function u should call like this:

```
person.amIOld() #or
per.amIOld() #here per is an object where we kept self as parameter in that function.
```

But one thing that u have to remember self should be first parameter in any function because compiler thinks first parameter in a function as representation of object(self).

## if u want any further clarification send me a message to me on shivashanker.chagamreddy@gmail.com.